# JasperReports Server REST returns 415 Unsupported Media Type

Tags: java, rest, jasperserver

I have created a Jasper Report on JasperReports Server. If I click it in the administrator web page, the report is correctly generated (by first querying my database) and rendered. I'd also like to run the report through the /reportExecutions REST call but I cannot get it to work. I'm using the following code to make the POST request:

```
String xml = ""
  + "<reportExecutionRequest>"
  + "..."
  + "</reportExecutionRequest>";

HttpPost post = new HttpPost(
  new URI("http://localhost:8080/rest_v2/reportExecutions"));
post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");
post.setEntity(new StringEntity(xml));

HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
```

My response always give me a 415 Unsupported Media Type error even though I specify the content type to be "application/xml" in the POST header. If I look at the Java stack trace output of the JasperReports server, it indicates the following:

```
Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: 
A message body reader for Java class 
com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.jaxrs.report. 
ReportExecutionRequest, and Java type class
com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.jaxrs.report.ReportExecutionRequest,
and MIME media type application/octet-stream was not found.
```

So, it looks it's receiving something with a content type "application/octet-stream" for which it cannot find a message body reader. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: The error message says you are sending your XML as `application/octet-stream`. Your code works fine on my jaspersever 6.2.1 instance with the httpclient-4.3.6. Maybe you have extra code that resets the content-type header.

Comment: I don't think I have extra code that might mess things up. I have it working right now. I do remember adding a HTTP Basic authentication header to the initial request. I think that made it work but then it fails on the next request which is to retrieve the request status. In the end, I solved that problem by using the login service and keep track of the session cookie. I couldn't get multiple requests to work with HTTP basic. Don't know why. It seems the server does not keep track of username/password based sessions while the login service does (based on the session cookie)

Answer (score 0):

Use `"Content-Type":"application/json"` in header its work